# How to create Joomla 3.0 Account using PHP File

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to create a joomla 3.0 user account using a php code, or a web app that I can run within joomla files. I've a thread similar to my problem here

[How can I create a new Joomla user account from within a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904809/how-can-i-create-a-new-joomla-user-account-from-within-a-script/1904855#1904855)

But the problem with this thread it is based on 1.5 and 2.5 Joomla Version. Ive read also that joomla 3.0 added salt hashing and concatenate it to the md5 password.

Perhaps if someone can give me a working php file that I can run so that I can create a new SUPER admin user on my joomla website.

By the way I can access the joomla files via ftp but I cannot access the database via phpmyadmin.

Comment: if you want someone to do the work for you, hire a freelancer. If you want us to help with your code, show us what you have tried.

Comment: Joomla 3.x uses `bcrypt`, not salt + md5 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the variables you mention, I answered a similiar question that included the PHP to create an account at [Joomla ACL integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486946/joomla-acl-integration/26487784#26487784).

Comment: I can't explain all of PHP for you here...you need to read and learn Object Oriented PHP:  $this is an $model is a PHP object, and  anything to the right of the -> is a method or property.  Methods are a function that is define within that object and are denoted with ().  Without the () then it is a property.  Try googling "introduction to object oriented php"

Comment: Take a look at http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/object-orientated-programming-in-php-class-1-principles.html  It's explained there - there's just way too much to explain in a few lines here.